# Azure Server Redirect module using get parameters

Tags: azure, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config

I try to make a permanent redirection on an azure website using the rewriting module using this pattern :

```
   <rule name="Rewrite redirect-not-found-products-w" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="product/Product.aspx?product_id=287"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/product" redirectType="Permanent"/>
   </rule>
```

But I would like take care of GET parameters

By example redirect :

example.com/product/Product.aspx?product_id=287

**or**

example.com/product/Product.aspx?product_id=35

**to**

example.com/product

**but not the whole product/Product.aspx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should have condition with query string, you cannot use query string in `match url=`

```
<rule name="Rewrite redirect-not-found-products-w"  stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^product/Product.aspx$" />      
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^product_id=287$" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^product_id=35$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/product" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Rule above will redirect:

example.com/product/Product.aspx?product_id=287

or

example.com/product/Product.aspx?product_id=35

to

example.com/product